# Convert the normal old 'for loop' to Java 8 'forEach'

Tags: java, java-stream

See below I am using old for loop and so many if conditions, I need your support to convert it into Java 8 forEach. I am very weak to solve this.

Here I am iterating the order object using the old for loop, at a time 500 data will send to a third-party server. **Because a third-party server will allow only 1500 rows of data at the time**. So I split the list based on limit 1500.

This is just my standalone class. My intention is to convert the old for loop to java 8 streams.

Comment: *Why* do you want to replace this with `forEach`

Comment: Using streams will not magically make code more readable, and certainly not faster. A first step towards readability would be refactoring your code to avoid having 3 distinct copy-pasted blocks that call `sendToCarwings`.

Comment: When refactoring such code, it is often good to start at the innermost scope. Extract the identical blocks to a method first.

Comment: @tucuxi indeed - my advice to OP would be to recast the code into a form that _first_ deals with breaking down the full request into a `List<List<Orders>>` where each list is at most 500 elements long. Then they can use a range-for to go through that and send each request.

Comment: This is just my standalone class, actually, I have optimized code with logger, command method everything. My intention is to convert the old for loop to java 8 streams.

Comment: Why do you want to convert the code to streams?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would suggest not going with the Streams option, because what you want is basically the opposite of a "flatMap", that is, take a stream of X and return a stream of Y, each of which is composed of several X.

In this self-contained example, the `chunkList` function "splits" a list into chunks, without making copies (because it just uses subList) and then your code can process that, separately from the chunking code - this would probably go in the `sendRequest` function, which I have just mocked by throwing if the size is too big for a single request. I think that represents your original problem fairly enough, but do tell me if it does not.

Again, you can basically "ignore" my `Orders` and `repo_findAll` implementations, they are basically mocks to make the example self-contained and testable.

```java
import java.util.List;

public class App 
{
    /** Your request size limit */
    private static final int MAX_REQ_SIZE = 500;

    /** Dummy representing your code that makes the HttpRequest. */
    public static void sendRequest(List<Orders> data) {
        if (data.size() > MAX_REQ_SIZE)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid request size");
        System.out.println("Sending request of size " + data.size());
    }

    /** Possibility without Stream shenanigans. This function just creates a list of sub-lists of its argument,
     * each with a size &le; the given chunk size. The returned value will:<ul>
     * <li>Be non-null, with maybe 0 elements if the original list is empty.</li>
     * <li>Have elements of size chunkSize for every element except the last</li>
     * <li>Ultimately contain just references to indices in the original list, in the same order</li>
     * </ul>
     */
    public static List<List<Orders>> chunkList(List<Orders> orig, final int chunkSize) {
        if (chunkSize <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        final List<List<Orders>> ret = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        int begin = 0;
        for (; begin + chunkSize <= orig.size(); begin += chunkSize) {
            ret.add(orig.subList(begin, begin + chunkSize));
        }
        if (begin < orig.size()) {
            ret.add(orig.subList(begin, orig.size()));
        }
        return ret;
    }
    
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // Your original dataset
        final List<Orders> data = repo_findAll();

        // The resulting operation
        for (List<Orders> curChunk : chunkList(data, MAX_REQ_SIZE)) {
            // You could place exception handling here to retry a chunk if it fails, etc
            sendRequest(curChunk);
        }
    }

    
    /** Dummy data class */
    private static class Orders {
        public final int number;
        public Orders(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return "Order #" + number;
        }
    }
    /** Dummy representing your orders-generating function. This one makes a list of random size ~0.5-3 times the max request size, per sizesRnd below */
    static List<Orders> repo_findAll() {
        final int genSize = sizesRnd.nextInt();
        return java.util.stream.IntStream.range(1,genSize+1)
                .mapToObj(Orders::new).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());
    }
    private static final java.util.PrimitiveIterator.OfInt sizesRnd = new java.util.Random().ints(MAX_REQ_SIZE/2, MAX_REQ_SIZE*3+20).iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you are trying to split a List into several sublists of a given size. Instead of determining the sublist during iteration, I would do this beforehand and then execute the identical further processing of the sublist, i.e

1. create a list of order lists of size 500 from your order list `List<Order> => List<List<Order>>`
2. iterate over the obove list of lists and send your request with one list at a time

Example

```
List<Orders> order = (List<Orders>) repo.findAll();
int chunkSize = 500;
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();

Collection<List<Orders>> chunkedOrders = order.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item -> ai.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize))
    .values();

//then the rest of your logic to send the requests
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

chunkedOrders.forEach(chunk -> {    
    HttpEntity<List<Orders>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<List<Orders>>(chunk, headers);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    System.out.println("Sending" + " " + chunk.size() + " " + "order data");
    sendToCarwings(restTemplate, requestEntity);
    System.out.println("Successfully sent" + " " + chunk.size() + " " + "order data");
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, @Eritrean. Shall I need to check the performance?

Comment: @sibinRasiya Performance may depend on many factors other than the above snippet. Compare this with your original implementation. If you notice a negative significant difference it may be worth a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

The loop alters minLimit and maxLimit, so a forEach is not adequate.

But you can improve the looping as follows:

```
    final int fixed = 500;
    int minLimit = 0;
    int maxLimit;
    for (maxLimit = fixed; maxLimit <= order.size(); maxLimit += fixed) {
            List<Orders> orderSubList = order.subList(minLimit, maxLimit);
            HttpEntity<List<Orders>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<List<Orders>>(orderSubList, headers);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            System.out.println("Sending" + " " + minLimit + " " + "to" + " " + maxLimit + " " + "order data");
            sendToCarwings(restTemplate, requestEntity);
            System.out
                    .println("Successfully sent" + " " + minLimit + " " + "to" + " "+maxLimit + " " + "order data");
            minLimit = maxLimit;
    }
```

Handling the order list differently might be more efficient; memory usage etc.